# Threads state after the program finishes execution

Tags: windows, multithreading

What happens to internal threads after the main thread finishes execution?

E.G:

Program 1 creates 5 threads to run in background. 
   Program 1 crashes. 
   Are those threads alive?

They will get killed because threads are bound in the process context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All those resources are linked up to the process data structure. When a process is terminated Windows ensures that **all** the resources are cleaned-up.

Didn't manage to find references to docs [feel free to add some, I am sure I read this in M.Russinovich "Windows Internals" book], but here are couple of similar answers regarding memory dealocations. Thread clean up is part of the clean up routine that windows call when a process is terminated.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2975844/706456

https://stackoverflow.com/a/654766/706456

Answer (score 1):

If a thread A creates a thread B and thread A terminates then thread B will not be killed as there is no parent/child relationship between threads.

The only situation where other threads are terminated is when the main process terminates (so, if the program crashes, they will get killed indeed).