# About Memory leaks(theoretical)

Tags: c

If I allocate (using malloc) 15 bytes every time I run a code without releasing the memory.lets assume I run the code 100 times so I have a leak of 1500 bytes (on a virtual machine).Does this memory ever released? or It is still out there taking a memory from my computer?

Comment: When your process terminates, the memory is reclaimed.

Comment: @MasterDarkNight I don't think this question needs any code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975831/is-leaked-memory-freed-up-when-the-program-exits

Comment: @Matti there must be something he would have tried so that he came across this problem

Comment: @MasterDarkNight no it is just curiosity.

Comment: @MasterDarkNight Does it really make a difference if the question is a full description of the problem? Not every question needs code.

Comment: Ok , sorry then